# VBS Script...opening two command window instead one

Tags: vbscript, vb6

I am using below vbs to launch one executable file to run as differenct user.. end user not technical person so he just double click vbs to launch tool..

Here, the issue is when user double click the vbs script, it opens two cmd window instead of one.

Any clue whats the cause?

```
  Option explicit
  Dim oShell
  set oShell= Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  oShell.Run "RunAs /user:NETMON\mikep ""\\Shared\executeME.exe"
  WScript.Sleep 100
  oShell.Sendkeys "password~"
  Wscript.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably should be

```
oShell.Run "RunAs /user:NETMON\mikep ""\\Shared\executeME.exe"""
```

your quotes aren't matched or closed properly.

Comment: I added two double quotes as you mentioned but still result same..two cmd opens..one launches exe and closes automatically and other one stays as it is...